# The definition of amplitude probability density

Tags: continuous-signals, random-process, probability, probability-distribution-function

I'm trying to figure out the formal definition of "amplitude probability density"(APD). First of all I didn't find a textbook which defines APD but there are some sources that explain it intuitively like [this](https://www.jvejournals.com/article/18772):
[image]

[image]
I first encountered APD when reading about Woodward's theorem. This is taken from "Communication Circuits: Analysis and Design" by Clarke & Hess:[image]
By looking at [this](http://users.metu.edu.tr/ccandan/EE306/Spring2011-12/homeworks/html/EE306_RandomProcesses3.html#1), it seems to me that we can find APD by finding the first-order pdf of $f(t, X)$ for some $t$ and $X$ is an uniform random variable but the problem still remains. What's the formal definition of APD? If we completely know $f(t)$, there is no probability to calculate. So it should be a realization of a random process.
Also I found another [source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/111826682X) which talks about pdf of a signal:
[image][image]
So maybe the word "probability" is totally misleading and APD is just amplitude distribution of a known signal? In that case, what's the formal definition of the amplitude distribution?

Comment: I’ve never heard the term before. Is it not just the probability density function of the amplitude of a signal? The pdf of a signal represents the probability of choosing any specific value when you choose randomly.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks. Do you have a formal definition for the probability density function of the amplitude of a signal? I couldn't find a formal definition.

Comment: It seems like you know what a pdf is. That’s all it is, any value in the signal can be considered a random variable and therefore it has a pdf. The formal definition is the formal definition of a pdf.